# Rider only build resources into dll

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, mono, rider

I tried to build my project with mono version 6.12.0 installed, it compiles without errors, but the classes don't seem to be compiled, when i test the file, it doesn't work and when im decompiling it, it is empty. The projects runtime version is 4.7.2, because the libary requires me to use that version, if thats the issue.

[image: Here is the decompiled File]

Comment: Unless you are with Xamarin bits or Unity, Mono isn't the platform to use. You have to migrate to .NET 6 or 8 as soon as possible.

Comment: @LexLi I use Unity, there mighty be a problem whith my csproject file, ill try figure it out